# Issue with gulp command : bower-install error

Tags: gulp, bower

Yesterday, my build was working fine nothing has changed. This morning, I just tried to execute "gulp" command and I have the following error:

> 'bower-install... events.js:154 throw er;  Error: write EPIPE

**My gulpfile.js:**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    eventStream = require('event-stream'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    through = require('through2'),
    lodash = require('lodash'),
    PoFile = require('pofile'),
    strftime = require('strftime'),
    del = require('del'),
    bower = require('bower'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    phpcs = require('gulp-phpcs'),
    order = require('gulp-order'),
    handlebars = require('gulp-handlebars'),
    handlebarsEngine = require('handlebars'),
    defineModule = require('gulp-define-module'),
    header = require('gulp-header'),
    zip = require('gulp-zip'),
    tar = require('gulp-tar'),
    gzip = require('gulp-gzip'),
    chmod = require('gulp-chmod'),
    xgettext = require('gulp-xgettext'),
    concatPo = require('gulp-concat-po'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

// Set global configs.
var config = {
    mibewPath: 'mibew',
    configsPath: 'mibew/configs',
    phpVendorPath: 'mibew/vendor',
    jsVendorPath: 'mibew/js/vendor',
    pluginsPath: 'mibew/plugins',
    avatarsPath: 'mibew/files/avatar',
    cachePath: 'mibew/cache',
    jsPath: 'mibew/js',
    chatStylesPath: 'mibew/styles/chats',
    pageStylesPath: 'mibew/styles/pages',
    compiledTemplatesHeader: fs.readFileSync('tools/compiled_templates_header.txt'),
    getComposerUrl: 'https://getcomposer.org/installer',
    phpBin: 'php -d "suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar"',
    package: require('./composer.json')
}


// Cleans all built files
gulp.task('clean', function(callback) {
    del([
        'release',
        'composer.lock',
        config.phpVendorPath,
        config.jsVendorPath,
        config.jsPath + '/compiled/**/*',
        '!' + config.jsPath + '/compiled/.keep',
        config.chatStylesPath + '/default/templates_compiled/client_side/*.js',
        config.chatStylesPath + '/default/js/compiled/*.js',
        config.pageStylesPath + '/default/templates_compiled/client_side/*.js'
    ], callback);
});

// Checks all PHP files with PHP Code Sniffer.
gulp.task('phpcs', ['composer-install-dev'], function() {
    return gulp.src([
        config.mibewPath + '/**/*.php',
        '!' + config.phpVendorPath + '/**/*.*',
        '!' + config.pluginsPath + '/**/*.*',
        '!' + config.cachePath + '/**/*.*'
    ], {
        // Content of the cache directory is readable only for webserver. Thus
        // we must to set "strict" option to false to prevent "EACCES" errors.
        // At the same we need to see all errors that take place.
        strict: false,
        silent: false
    })
    .pipe(phpcs({
        bin: config.phpVendorPath + '/bin/phpcs',
        standard: 'PSR2',
        warningSeverity: 0
    }))
    .pipe(phpcs.reporter('log'))
    .pipe(phpcs.reporter('fail'));
});

// Get and install PHP Composer
gulp.task('get-composer', function(callback) {
    // Check if Composer already in place
    if (fs.existsSync('./composer.phar')) {
        callback(null);

        return;
    }

    // Get installer from the internet
    https.get(config.getComposerUrl, function(response) {
        // Run PHP to install Composer
        var php = exec(config.phpBin, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            callback(error ? stderr : null);
        });
        // Pass installer code to PHP via STDIN
        response.pipe(php.stdin);
    });
});

// Install Composer dependencies excluding development ones
gulp.task('composer-install', ['get-composer'], function(callback) {
    exec(config.phpBin + ' composer.phar install --no-dev', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        callback(error ? stderr : null);
    });
});

// Install all Composer dependencies
gulp.task('composer-install-dev', ['get-composer'], function(callback) {
    exec(config.phpBin + ' composer.phar install', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        callback(error ? stderr : null);
    });
});

// Installs bower dependencies
gulp.task('bower-install', function(callback) {
    bower.commands.install([], {}, {})
        .on('error', function(error) {
            callback(error);
        })
        .on('end', function() {
            // We should manually minify JavaScript files that was not minified
            // by bower packages' authors.
            // TODO: This is a temproary workaround and should be removed once
            // the packages will be fixed.
            var stream = eventStream.merge(
                gulp.src(config.jsVendorPath + '/backbone/backbone.js', {base: config.jsVendorPath})
                    .pipe(uglify({preserveComments: 'some'}))
                    // There are neither "@license" tag nor "!preserve" in the
                    // header. Add the header manually.
                    .pipe(header(
                        "// Backbone.js 1.1.2\n"
                            + "// (c) 2010-2015 Jeremy Ashkenas, DocumentCloud and Investigative Reporters & Editors\n"
                            + "// Backbone may be freely distributed under the MIT license.\n"
                            + "// For all details and documentation:\n"
                            + "// http://backbonejs.org\n"
                    ))
                    .pipe(rename('backbone/backbone-min.js')),
                gulp.src(config.jsVendorPath + '/json/json2.js', {base: config.jsVendorPath})
                    .pipe(uglify({preserveComments: 'some'}))
                    // There are neither "@license" tag nor "!preserve" in the
                    // header. Add the header manually.
                    .pipe(header("// json2.js. Public Domain. See http://www.JSON.org/js.html\n"))
                    .pipe(rename('json/json2.min.js'))
            )
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.jsVendorPath));

            stream
                .on('error', callback)
                .on('end', callback);
        });
});

// Compile all JavaScript files of the Mibew Core
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return eventStream.merge(
        getClientSideApp('default'),
        getClientSideApp('chat'),
        getClientSideApp('thread_log'),
        getClientSideApp('users'),
        gulp.src(config.jsPath + '/source/**/*.js')
    )
    .pipe(uglify({preserveComments: 'some'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.jsPath + '/compiled'));
});

// Performs all job related with chat styles.
gulp.task('chat-styles', ['chat-styles-handlebars', 'chat-styles-js'], function() {
    // This task is just a combination of other tasks. That is why there is no
    // real code.
});

// Compile and concatenate handlebars files for all chat styles.
gulp.task('chat-styles-handlebars', function() {
    // TODO: Process all available styles, not only the default one.
    var stylePath = config.chatStylesPath + '/default';

    return gulp.src(stylePath + '/templates_src/client_side/**/*.handlebars')
        .pipe(handlebars({
            // Use specific version of Handlebars.js
            handlebars: handlebarsEngine
        }))
        .pipe(wrapHandlebarsTemplate())
        .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
        .pipe(uglify({preserveComments: 'some'}))
        .pipe(header(config.compiledTemplatesHeader))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(stylePath + '/templates_compiled/client_side'));
});

// Compile and concatenate js files for all chat styles.
gulp.task('chat-styles-js', function() {
    // TODO: Process all available styles, not only the default one.
    var stylePath = config.chatStylesPath + '/default';

    return gulp.src(stylePath + '/js/source/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(uglify({preserveComments: 'some'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(stylePath + '/js/compiled'));
});

// Performs all job related with pages styles.
gulp.task('page-styles', function() {
    // TODO: Process all available styles, not only the default one.
    var stylePath = config.pageStylesPath + '/default';

    return gulp.src(stylePath + '/templates_src/client_side/**/*.handlebars')
        .pipe(handlebars({
            // Use specific version of Handlebars.js
            handlebars: handlebarsEngine
        }))
        .pipe(wrapHandlebarsTemplate())
        .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
        .pipe(uglify({preserveComments: 'some'}))
        .pipe(header(config.compiledTemplatesHeader))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(stylePath + '/templates_compiled/client_side'));
});

// Generate .pot files based on the sources
gulp.task('generate-pot', function() {
    return eventStream.merge(
        gulp.src([
            config.mibewPath + '/**/*.php',
            '!' + config.phpVendorPath + '/**/*.*',
            '!' + config.pluginsPath + '/**/*.*',
            '!' + config.cachePath + '/**/*.*'
        ], {
            // Content of the cache directory is readable only for webserver.
            // Thus we must to set "strict" option to false to prevent "EACCES"
            // errors. At the same we need to see all errors that take place.
            strict: false,
            silent: false
        })
            .pipe(xgettext({
                language: 'PHP',
                keywords: [
                    {name: 'getlocal'},
                    {name: 'no_field'},
                    {name: 'wrong_field'},
                    {name: 'failed_uploading_file', singular: 2}
                ]
            })),
        gulp.src(config.jsPath + '/source/**/*.js', {base: config.mibewPath})
            .pipe(xgettext({
                language: 'JavaScript',
                keywords: [
                    {name: 'trans'}
                ]
            })),
        gulp.src([
            config.chatStylesPath + '/default/templates_src/**/*.handlebars',
            config.pageStylesPath + '/default/templates_src/**/*.handlebars'
        ], {base: config.mibewPath})
            .pipe(xgettextHandlebars())
    )
    .pipe(concatPo('translation.pot', {
        headers: {
            'Project-Id-Version': 'Mibew Messenger ' + config.package.version,
            'Report-Msgid-Bugs-To': config.package.support.email,
            'POT-Creation-Date': strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%z'),
            'PO-Revision-Date': '',
            'Last-Translator': '',
            'Language-Team': '',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('release'));
});

// Pack sources to .zip and .tar.gz archives.
gulp.task('pack-sources', ['composer-install', 'bower-install'], function() {
    var sources = [
        config.mibewPath + '/**/*',
        // Exclude user's config
        '!' + config.configsPath + '/config.yml',
        // Exclude cache files but not the ".keep" file.
        '!' + config.cachePath + '/**/!(.keep)',
        // Exclude avatars but not the ".keep" file.
        '!' + config.avatarsPath + '/!(.keep)',
        // Exclude plugins but not the ".keep" file.
        '!' + config.pluginsPath + '/!(.keep)',
        '!' + config.pluginsPath + '/*/**/*',
        // Exclude Git repositories that can be shipped with third-party libs
        '!' + config.phpVendorPath + '/**/.git',
        '!' + config.phpVendorPath + '/**/.git/**/*',
        // Exclude vendors binaries
        '!' + config.phpVendorPath + '/bin/**/*',
        // Exclude JavaScript sources
        '!' + config.jsPath + '/source/**/*',
        // Actually we does not need backbone.babysitter and backbone.wreqr
        // dependencies because they embed into marionette.js. So we exclude
        // "backbone.babysitter" and "backbone.wreqr" directories and all their
        // contents.
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/backbone.babysitter{,/**}',
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/backbone.wreqr{,/**}',
        // Exclude dot files within third-party JS libraries.
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/**/.*',
        // Exclude config files of various package systems
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/**/{bower,component,package,composer}.json',
        // Exclude config files of various build systems
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/**/Gruntfile.*',
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/**/gulpfile.*',
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/**/Makefile',
        // Exclude HTML files from third-party JS libraries. Such files can be
        // used for docs or for tests, we need none of them.
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/**/*.html',
        // There are too many useless files in Vex.js library. Exclude them.
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/vex/sass{,/**}',
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/vex/docs{,/**}',
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/vex/docs{,/**}',
        '!' + config.jsVendorPath + '/vex/coffee{,/**}'
    ];
    var srcOptions = {
        // Dot files (.htaccess, .keep, etc.) must be included in the package.
        dot: true,
        // Content of the cache directory is readable only for webserver. Thus
        // we must to set "strict" option to false to prevent "EACCES" errors.
        // At the same we need to see all errors that take place.
        strict: false,
        silent: false
    }
    var version = config.package.version;

    return eventStream.merge(
        gulp.src(sources, srcOptions)
            .pipe(zip('mibew-' + version + '.zip')),
        gulp.src(sources, srcOptions)
            .pipe(tar('mibew-' + version + '.tar'))
            .pipe(gzip())
    )
    .pipe(chmod(0644))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('release'));
});

// Performs all tasks in the correct order.
gulp.task('prepare-release', function(callback) {
    runSequence(
        'clean',
        ['phpcs', 'js', 'chat-styles', 'page-styles', 'generate-pot'],
        'pack-sources',
        callback
    );
});

// Prepares ready to use development version of Mibew without packing or
// validating it.
gulp.task('rebuild', function(callback) {
    runSequence(
        'clean',
        ['js', 'chat-styles', 'page-styles', 'composer-install', 'bower-install'],
        callback
    );
});

// Builds the sources
gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    runSequence(
        'clean',
        ['js', 'chat-styles', 'page-styles'],
        'pack-sources',
        callback
    );
});


/**
 * Loads and prepare js file for a client side application with the specified
 * name.
 *
 * @param {String} name Application name
 * @returns A files stream that can be piped to any gulp plugin.
 */
var getClientSideApp = function(name) {
    var appSource = config.jsPath + '/source/' + name;

    return gulp.src(appSource + '/**/*.js')
        .pipe(order(
            [
                appSource + '/init.js',
                // The following line is equivalent to
                // gulp.src([appSource + '/*.js', '!' + appSource + '/app.js']);
                appSource + '/!(app).js',
                appSource + '/models/**/base*.js',
                appSource + '/models/**/*.js',
                appSource + '/collections/**/base*.js',
                appSource + '/collections/**/*.js',
                appSource + '/model_views/**/base*.js',
                appSource + '/model_views/**/*.js',
                appSource + '/collection_views/**/base*.js',
                appSource + '/collection_views/**/*.js',
                appSource + '/regions/**/base*.js',
                appSource + '/regions/**/*.js',
                appSource + '/layouts/**/base*.js',
                appSource + '/layouts/**/*.js',
                appSource + '/**/base*.js',
                // The following line is equivalent to
                // gulp.src([appSource + '/**/*.js', '!' + appSource + '/app.js']);
                '!' + appSource + '/app.js',
                appSource + '/app.js'
            ],
            {base: process.cwd()}
        ))
        .pipe(concat(name + '_app.js'));
}

/**
 * Wraps a handlebars template with a function and attach it to the
 * Handlebars.templates object.
 *
 * @returns {Function} A function that can be used in pipe() method of a file
 *   stream right after gulp-handlebars plugin.
 */
var wrapHandlebarsTemplate = function() {
    return defineModule('plain', {
        wrapper: '(function() {\n'
            + 'var templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};\n'
            + 'Handlebars.templates["<%= relative %>"] = <%= handlebars %>;\n'
            + '})()',
        context: function(context) {
            return {relative: context.file.relative.replace(/\.js$/, '').replace(/\\/g, '/')};
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Extracts gettext messages from handlebars templates.
 *
 * @returns {Function} A function that can be used in pipe() method of a file
 *   stream.
 */
var xgettextHandlebars = function() {
    var helperRegExp = /\{{2}l10n\s*('|")(.*?[^\\])\1.*?\}{2}/g;

    return through.obj(function (file, enc, callback) {
        var po = new PoFile();
            match = false,
            contents = file.contents.toString();

        while (match = helperRegExp.exec(contents)) {
            // Try to find item in the .po file by its name.
            var item = lodash.find(po.items, function(item) {
                return match[2] === item.msgid;
            });

            var line = contents.substr(0, match.index).split(/\r?\n|\r/g).length;

            if (!item) {
                // There is no such item. Create new one.
                item = new PoFile.Item();
                item.msgid = match[2].replace(/\\'/g, "'").replace(/\\"/g, '"');
                po.items.push(item);
            }

            // Add new reference
            item.references.push(file.relative + ':' + line);
        }

        // Update file contents
        file.contents = new Buffer(po.toString());
        this.push(file);

        callback();
    });
}
```

Comment: Make sure node and npm are up to date. Dependencies can break previously-functioning applications

Comment: Hello Wes Foster, thank you very much for your quick reply. I am using npn version 3.7.3 and node js version 5.9.1

Comment: What's on line 154 of events.js?

Comment: Crazy, I am not even able to find events.js file in my project Wes Foster. Crazyyyyyy

Comment: Oufff. This is what I have on line 154:  if (res.headers[header])

Comment: Hello everyone, I solved the problem. I just need to reinstall manually composer.phar